# What is alternative of deleted Money#decimal_places_display?

Tags: python, django

I stuck a bit with hiding decimals of Money object. Ex:

```
In [51]: str(Money(123, 'USD'))
Out[51]: 'US$123.00'
```

returns with 00 in the end.
Before it was resolved by `money_obj.decimal_places_display = 0` but it is deleted in the last version on djmoney https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id3

I have tried to use babel [format_currency](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html#pattern-syntax), but no success. The decimals are there so far:

```
In [54]: from babel.numbers import format_currency
    ...: format_currency(12345, 'USD', format='¤#')
Out[54]: '$12345.00'
```

For now my solution is quite manual, and the question is it possible to make it better?

```
In [55]: from babel.numbers import format_decimal
    ...: from djmoney.money import Money
    ...:
    ...: from utils.constants import CURRENCIES_CHOICES
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: def format_int(money: Money) -> str:
    ...:     amount = format_decimal(round(money.amount), locale='en_GB')
    ...:     currency = format_currency(0, str(money.currency), format='¤')
    ...:     return f'{currency} {amount}'
    ...:
    ...: format_int(Money(12345, 'USD'))
    ...:
Out[55]: '$ 12,345'
```

Comment: Linked question on djmoney github https://github.com/django-money/django-money/issues/724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babel`'s `format_currency` allows us to display the rounded amount by  passing a format string and `currency_digits=False`.

However, by using a format string we lose the ability to localize the amount and the placement of the currency sign.

Example:

```py
# Python 3.12.2
# Babel==2.14.0

from babel.numbers import format_currency


# This is OK, since in en_GB the currency sign goes before the amount
format_currency(
    currency='USD',
    currency_digits=False,
    format='¤#',
    locale='en_GB',
    number=42.24,
)  # US$42

# This overrides the placement of the currency sign in fr_FR
format_currency(
    currency='USD',
    currency_digits=False,
    format='¤#',
    locale='fr_FR',
    number=42.24,
)  # $US42
```

If we omit the format string, then we see that in French the currency symbol should go after the amount:

```
format_currency(
    currency='USD',
    currency_digits=False,
    locale='fr_FR',
    number=42.24,
)  # 42,24\xa0$US
```

We can round the amount and keep the localized format by using a helper function, e.g. the function published in [this comment](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/478#issuecomment-290365787) or an adapted version which always rounds the amount:

```py
from babel import Locale


def format_currency_no_decimals(
    currency,
    number,
    locale,
    **kwargs,
):
    locale_ = Locale.parse(locale)
    pattern = locale_.currency_formats["standard"]
    return pattern.apply(
        number, locale_, currency=currency, force_frac=(0, 0), **kwargs
    )


format_currency_no_decimals(
    currency='USD',
    locale='en_GB',
    number=42.24,
)  # US$42
format_currency_no_decimals(
    currency='USD',
    locale='fr_FR',
    number=42.24,
)  # 42\xa0$US
```

Note: we will get a deprecation warning when calling `pattern.apply`: `DeprecationWarning: The force_frac parameter to NumberPattern.apply() is deprecated.`, so this solution isn't future proof.

We can also override the currency symbol for a specific locale, e.g.:

```py
from babel import Locale


Locale.parse("en_GB").currency_symbols["USD"] = "$"

format_currency(currency='USD', locale='en_GB', number=42.24)  # $42.24
format_currency_no_decimals(currency='USD', locale='en_GB', number=42.24)  # $42
```